# Extract nodes coordinates according to local Csys_Abaqus Python scripting

Tags: python, scripting, abaqus

[image]

I wrote a script that will extract nodes coordinates according to a local System. Because coordinates are generated by default according to the global system.

```
odb = openOdb(path='.....................Job-1.odb')

Setnodes = 'LocalnodesCoord.txt'
NodesFile = open(Setnodes,'w')

nodeset='NODESET-3'
mySet = odb.rootAssembly.instances['PART-1-1'].nodeSets[nodeset]

csys1=odb.rootAssembly.datumCsyses['CSYS-1']


lastFrame = odb.steps['Step-1'].frames[-1] 
coords=lastFrame.fieldOutputs['COORD']


mySetCoord = coords.getSubset(region=mySet)
mySetCoord_local=mySetCoord.getTransformedField(datumCsys=csys1)
mySetCoordLocalValues=mySetCoord_local.values


for var in mySetCoordLocalValues :
    
    NodesFile.write(str(var.nodeLabel) + ',' + str(var.data[0]) + ',' + str(var.data[1]) + ',' + str(var.data[2])+ '\n')
  

NodesFile.close()
odb.close()
```

I used the ***getTransformedField()*** function. but the problem I get wrong coordinates

can you help me to solve this problem.
do you have any idea how to determine the transformation matrix?

Comment: You can just get the coordinates with respect to global coordinate system and subtract the center coordinates of local coordinates system from it. For ex. if (x,y,z) are the coordinates of a point A in global coordinate system, (x0,y0,z0) is the center of local coordinates system. Then coordinates of point A in local coordinates system will be (x1,y1,z1) = ( x-x0, y-y0, z-z0).

Comment: Satish Thorat, thank you for your reply. But I think when there is a rotation and translation between local and global coordinates systems, we can not use this method.

Answer (score 1):

From [documentation](http://194.167.201.93/English/SIMACAECMDRefMap/simacmd-c-odbintrotranscpp.htm):

> If the system is model based, you must supply a displacement field that determines the instantaneous location and orientation of the coordinate system

Probably, as your Local Csys is moving with the geometry, Abaqus needs additional information to calculate transformation.
So, try suppling the `getTransformedField` method with the `deformationField` and the `rotationField` as described [here](http://abaqus.software.polimi.it/v6.14/books/ker/default.htm?startat=pt01ch34pyo06.html#ker-fieldoutput-gettransformedfield3-pyc)

#### Edit

Or, as proposed by @SatishThorat in his comment. Don't forget to use `numpy` module for the vectors arithmetics.

Answer (score 0):

@Roman Zhuravlev, Thank you very much for your answer.

FYI, I used many partition faces and for each one I assciated a fixed local coordinate system (and not a moving Csys).

I defined the local Csys by using three points : the origin and two others points according the global Csys.
so, I think these arguments are enough to calculate the transformation.